# Is the regression model best for the inventory data

Tags: machine-learning

I'm very new to the machine learning and currently i have a realtime project that needs a forecasting of the inventory required for the coming months.

I have a dataset for the last 3 years. Data set is very clean(no null, no duplicates)

Example of the data
year_month device_type person_type # of devices
2017-01       laptop      employee     2
2017-01       desktop      temp        5

like this i have the data till December 2019 now i need to predict for the feb 2020

Request someone to suggest which model need to be used?

As per me i'm look at Linear regression

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming, it is about statistical methodology.

Comment: Hi Mark... I'm looking at the complete steps involved in developing a model. for example for linear regression.